# How I can get current date in xml in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am adding group by filter of past due in accounting tab in odoo. And want to get context **due_date < current date**, but i am not getting current date anywhere, I don't know how i can get it, anybody can tell me that how to get current date in odoo?

**here is my group by filter**

```html
<xpath expr="//filter[@string='Due Month']" position="after
   <filter string="Past Due" context="{'group_by':'date_due < current date'}"/>
</xpath>
```

**and here is my other code in which i did it with computed field but don't how i can get current date**

```
@api.depends('date_due')
@api.multi
def _compute_due_date(self):
    for record in self:
        record.past_due = record.date_due < record.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xpath expr="//filter[@string='Due Month']" position="after
   <filter string="Past Due" name="past_due_filter" domain="[('date_due','&lt;',current_date)]" />

</xpath>
```

Comment: current field date is not existing there

Comment: It should not be using a field value. `current_date` is a global variable.

Comment: Hmmm.... its possible the `current_date` is not available within context.

Comment: can you do it with computed field which i added above with the computed functionality

Comment: It should be available within domain tag. This will only display records past due.

Comment: I see many examples accessing the current date within the domain however not the context. It is possible the scope is different here.

Comment: You can try with computed. Some functionality is unavailable for computed fields. Please update with whatever works for you. Can you use a domain as my example above?

Comment: Be careful NOT to use quotes for `current_date`

Comment: If you want to mark this as correct I wont hold it against you.

Comment: how to add days to current_date ? for example current_date +1days ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "context_today" or `time` module, examples:

```
 <filter name="today" string="Today" domain="[('date','=',time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"/>

 <filter name="last_24h" string="Last 24h" domain="[('start_date','&gt;', (context_today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]"/>
```

Comment: how to add days to current_date ? for example current_date +1days ?